# Error inserting options table in documentation

Tags: workbench

I have a Project named `MyProject`. In it I have the [recommended](https://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/reference/DocumentationTools/tutorial/AuthoringTutorialPagesUsingDocumentationTools.html) structure for a project. I've been writing the documentation for many of the functions I've added to my *MyProject\MyProject\MyProject.m* file, with the help of `PacletInfo.m` interface, available in the workbench.

Until now all functions without options work well and the documentation also. Now I'm having trouble with documenting ones with options.

**Problem**:
In the documentation editor, when I try to create an `Options Table`, with the Documentation Tools Palette, I get the message:

> OptionsTableCreate::nosymsfound: The link base MyProject appears to be incorrect for MyFunction. Reset $LinkBase and then try again.

I followed all instructions for setting up documentation and I don't understand what is happening. LinkBase is set to `MyProject` as is supposed and the Paclet path is in the `English` folder.

Maybe what is happening is that I'm no setting the options correctly for `MyFunction`.

Here's the basic structure of my package and where I place the options:

```
BeginPackage["MyProject`"]

MyFunc::usage = 
  "MyFunc[arg1] does amazing things with arg1."

Begin["`Private`"]

Options[MyFunc]={Op1->True, Op2->3};
MyFunc[arg1_, OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Module[{},
    (* MyFunc's core *)
  ];

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

Also, placing the options on the public part, above `MyFunc::usage =` makes no difference.

Comment: The code is ok. Where did you install the documentation palette from?

Comment: If you use the Workbench doc tools, a warning for you: Who will be using your package? What version of Mathematica do they have? How long do you plan to support that version?  Documentation generated with the current doc tools already doesn't look ideal in M11.1+.  What Wolfram comes out with new doc tools whose output doesn't work at al in M11.0 and earlier? Are you going to drop support for those versions *just because of the documentation*?

Comment: BTW, to ensure proper compatibility, you should already be generating the documentation using the oldest version of Mathematica you want to support.

Comment: I do not know why this problem occurs (the doc tools tend to be quite finicky), but I do see a problem in your sample code: `Op1` *should* be made a public symbol by mentioning it after `BeginPackage`. (This very likely is not the cause of the error.)

Comment: I see. So there must be another issue with the setup I'll need to figure out.
@Szabolcs Good questions. Right now I'm writing this code for all the workers at my lab. We use Mathematica 9, 10 and 11 in our computers, and probably later releases as well. Documenting this way would be nice, as pressing F1 would show documentation in any version right away. I was looking into workbench as a way to "do it properly", but I guess it's not quite there.

Comment: @ Szabolcs Making `Options[MyFunc]={Op1->True, Op2->3};` public still has the same issue. Is this what you mean by "mentioning it"?

Comment: By "mentioning" I meant that you need to write `Op1` between `BeginPackage[...]` and ``Begin["`Private`"]``, to ensure that it will be part of the context ``MyPackage` `` and not ``MyPackage`Private` ``.  This may be done in any way, but it is typically as `Op1::usage = "...";`.  However, `Op1` alone in that section of the package would be sufficient to ensure that the `Op1` symbol is created in the right context.